# How to add a new object with AngularJS and mongoDB

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using NodeJS, ANgularJS, and MongoDB with mongoose to make a website.  I'm having some trouble adding an object in mongoDB.  The name of the object is *Todo*.

Here are the models of Todo:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var TodoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    password : String,
    completed: Boolean,
    note: String  
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Todo', TodoSchema);
```

In the controller I create a new Todo and push it

```
angular.module('app').controller('Connexion', ['$scope', 'Todos','$location', function($scope,Todos, $location) {

$scope.editing = [];
$scope.todos = Todos.query();

$scope.save = function() {
    var todo = new Todos({ name: "test", password: "test", completed: false });
        $scope.todos.push(todo);
        Todos.save($scope.todo);
}
}]);
```

This is my html page, each time I click on the button I Have a new todo created and it's displayed on screen:

```
   <button ng-click="save()">Creer POST </button>

    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="todo in todos">
            {{todo.name}}
            {{todo.password}}

       </li>
   </ul>
```

But I have a problem, the new object is not added on the database.  How can I do it?

This is my files in the back-end :

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Todo = require('../models/Todo.js');

/* GET /todos listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
   Todo.find(function (err, todos) {
      if (err) return next(err);
           res.json(todos);
   });
});

/* POST /todos */
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
   Todo.create(req.body, function (err, post) {
      if (err) return next(err);
        res.json(post);
   });
});

/* GET /todos/id */
router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
   Todo.findById(req.params.id, function (err, post) {
       if (err) return next(err);
          res.json(post);
    });
});


/* PUT /todos/:id */
router.put('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
   Todo.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, function (err, post) {
       if (err) return next(err);
          res.json(post);
   });
});

/* DELETE /todos/:id */
router.delete('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    Todo.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, req.body, function (err, post) {
     if (err) return next(err);
       res.json(post);
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

And if this can help this the back-end file app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var mongo = require('mongodb');
var Post = require('./models/Post.js');

var routes = require('./routes/index');

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/todoApp', function(err) {
   if(err) {
      console.log('connection error', err);
   } else {
      console.log('connection successful');
   }
});


var app = express();
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', function(req, res, next){
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});

var found = ['DB Connection not yet established.  Try again later.   Check the console output for error messages if this persists.'];


module.exports = app;
```

Comment: What of that stuff should happen on the server? And what in the Angular app on the user's browser? Mongoose is a Node.js module for server-side database access, Angular is used for creating websites. I recommend you to read up on how the MEAN stack works.

Comment: Can you post what code is in your server? But maybe it's better for you to read something about MEAN stack before you try to do something with it, in particularly the server part.

Comment: Can you post also, the Todos service code ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer guys 
I want to interact between the front-end with angularJS and the back-end with nodeJs
I have a file in the back-end and I'm using json, i edited my post.

Comment: How can I comunicate between AngularJS and NodeJS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$scope.todo` from `Todos.save($scope.todo);` is not defined so this is why you might not manage to save anything

Comment: Yes I try to do this inside the          $scope.save = function()   I put this :                                                                                                                         









 todo.$save(function(){

            $scope.todos.push(todo)

 });

But the todo don't want to go to the database

Comment: you don't have anywhere defined **$scope.todo**, you have local variable **todo** and array **$scope.todos**

Comment: so try in your code `Todos.save(todo)` or `Todos.save($scope.todos)` depending on what you actually want to save in the database

Comment: I need to create a new function $scope.todo?

Comment: no, you can just save either of the two (the object or the array) you already have

Comment: How can i do it ? I try so many things and I don't understand the problem the $scope.todos is delclared up it's $scope.todos = Todos.query(); and I use Todos.save($scope.todos);

Comment: try to save only the last object added with `Todos.save(todo)`

Comment: or, depending on how your `Todos` looks like you would be able to save the new object using `todo.save()`